# How to UPDATE in one table in SQL based on matching data in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I found several questions with similar wording, but none addressed the specific question I have.

How does one perform an UPDATE with conditions that operate between two unlinked tables?

As example

```
TABLE_I
ID, Placed, junk, junk, junk

TABLE_II
ID, Category, Placed, Note, junk, junk...
```

If the Condition is in TABLE_II

```
WHERE Category=9 AND Note=@testvalue
```

An UPDATE should take place where a value in TABLE_II matches one in TABLE_I

```
 UPDATE TABLE_I SET Placed=@testvalue WHERE
```

.. the Current `TABLE_I.Placed=Table_II.Placed` assuming the above conditions are met

Is such stepped-in conditioning even possible in SQL?  Or would it require coding outside of the query to test in steps?

Comment: Sorry for the run-on in An UPDATE...
I'm not familiar with the formatting here yet.

Comment: MySQL and/or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: The syntax for an `UPDATE` with a join varies by database, are you using SQL Server?

Comment: A remote SQL-Server, but there is a local cut-down which is running on mySQL.. which is why I included both.

Comment: check my answer for both SQL and Mysql

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
  update t1 SET t1.Placed=@testvalue
    from Table_1 t1 
    join Table_2 t2 on t1.placed = t2.placed 
    where  t2.Category=9 AND t2.Note=@testvalue
```

you have to use join in the update statement

**Mysql**

the answer is yes you can

try it like that

```
 update Table_1 t1
    join Table_2 t2 on t1.placed = t2.placed 
    where  t2.Category=9 AND t2.Note=@testvalue
    SET t1.Placed=@testvalue
```

EDIT:

For general Update join :

```
   UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this kind of stuff with a trigger on insert on table_i combined with a procedure for updating the first table. 
Not sure on how to do it in MySQL or SQL-server (why 2 tags? Which is it?), but it probably is not much different from doing this in PostgreSQL. A quick Google search gave me http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Though the best solution probably is to actually link the unlinked tables.